# How can I automate checking the menus for integrity in a C++ app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, automation, menu, menuitem

In my C++ solution there are two projects : a SDI app and a MDI app.

Both have quite a lot of menus, and I often make changes (add / delete / replace menus).
Instead of checking for correctness myself (I'm error-prone, you know), I would love to have an automation for this.

Ideally it would warn me for either not having a handler for some menu at all, or having no code in the handler, like this :

```
void CDocument::OnDoThis()
{
}
```

Do you know any nice way to do this ?  ( I am using VS if it matters )

Answer (score 0):

You can send the WM_COMMAND message that the menu would send directly to the window you wish to control.